# Publish null/tombstone message with raw headers

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-kafka

I am building a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka processor app that will consume raw data with a String key and sometimes a null payload from a Kafka topic. I want to produce to another topic a String key and the null payload (known as a tombstone within Kafka). In order to use raw headers on the message, I need to output a `byte[]`, but if I encode `KafkaNull.INSTANCE` into a `byte[]` it will literally output a String of the object hashcode.

If I try to send anything other than a `byte[]`, I can't use raw headers.

What is the correct way to do this? Where would the headers even be if the payload is null? I set `producer.headerMode=embeddedHeaders` on deploy and that didn't seem to make a difference, still have the hashcode as the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the latter introduced `useNativeEncoding` property (which overlaps the `raw` `headerMode` in that it skips headers) but allows you use a native Kafka serializer.

See http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-docs/Brooklyn.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_producer_properties or http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-stream-docs/Chelsea.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_producer_properties

Comment: Ah, right, of course, so a `KafkaNull` payload will work with that mode. `spring-integration-kafka` uses a "special" message payload `KafkaNull.INSTANCE` to represent a null payload.

Comment: I think we should treat if it doesn't as a bug ... Maybe we can have a similar convention at the core level and do the translation in the binder.

Comment: Thanks. I am using KafkaNull.Instance when I produce. How do I override the producer serializer? I added several configs and nothing seems to change it, both in the stream def and deployment props. In fact the consumer warned it picked up an extra config value.serializer which makes sense, but the producer is still set to use bytearray serializer.

Comment: --spring.cloud.stream.output.producer.useNativeEncoding=true --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configuration.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Comment: Tried this locally with the same set of configurations and it worked (Brooklyn.SR3) . A couple questions - is your channel named `output` ? How can you tell that the valuee serializer is not set? There will be two producer configurations logged - one is for querying metadata - you should check the second one.

Comment: This worked locally (w/Brooklyn SR3) - note the correct setting for `useNativeEncoding`: `--spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.useNativeEncoding=true --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.configu‌​‌​ration.value.seria‌​li‌​zer=org.apache.k‌​afka‌​.common.serial‌​izatio‌​n.StringSeri‌​alizer`

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help!