# Unable to send message with KafkaNull as Value

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am building a Kafka Application Using Log Compaction on a Topic but I am not able to send a Tombstone Value (KafkaNull)

I have tried using the default configuration for a serializer and when that did not work I used the suggested changes from "[Publish null/tombstone message with raw headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960237/publish-null-tombstone-message-with-raw-headers)" To set the application.properties to:

```
spring.cloud.stream.output.producer.useNativeEncoding=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.value.serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

The code I have to send a message to a stream is

```
this.stockTopics.compactedStocks().send(MessageBuilder
    .withPayload(KafkaNull.INSTANCE)
    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY,company.getBytes())
    .build())
```

this.stopTopics.compactedStocks() returns a messageStream that I can send messages to.

Every time I try and send that message with a KafkaNull instance as a payload I get the error `Failed to convert message: 'GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaNull@1c2d8163, headers={id=f81857e7-fbd0-56f5-8418-6a1944e7f2b1, kafka_messageKey=[B@36ec022a, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1547827957485}]' to outbound message.`

I expect the message to simply be sent to the consumer with a null value but obviously it errors.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full stack trace.

Comment: Also, what makes you believe that KafkaNull is `application/json` convertible? The `Failed to convert message:...` simply means that no suitable message converter was found (we bootstrap you with 7 by default). But you can easily provide your own MessageConverter implementation as a bean annotated with [@StreamMessageConverter](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-user-defined-message-converters)

Comment: Reproduced - I think we need a standard converter for `KafkaNull` - the outbound channel adapter sends `KafkaNull` as `null`, so the channel interceptor needs to pass it unchanged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/531) for this.

**EDIT**

Workaround - this works...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class So54257687Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54257687Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        return args -> output.send(new GenericMessage<>(KafkaNull.INSTANCE));
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "output")
    public void listen(@Payload(required = false) byte[] in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    @StreamMessageConverter
    public MessageConverter kafkaNullConverter() {
        class KafkaNullConverter extends AbstractMessageConverter {

            KafkaNullConverter() {
                super(Collections.emptyList());
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
                return KafkaNull.class.equals(clazz);
            }

            @Override
            protected Object convertFromInternal(Message<?> message, Class<?> targetClass, Object conversionHint) {
                return message.getPayload();
            }

            @Override
            protected Object convertToInternal(Object payload, MessageHeaders headers, Object conversionHint) {
                return payload;
            }

        }
        return new KafkaNullConverter();
    }

}
```